Digital filter output understanding
I have following digital signal which has been retrieved via sampling of an analog signal with sampling period $T_s = 100\,\mu\mathrm{s}$

I have evaluated the frequency spectrum of this signal with the help of Scilab fft command
// analyzed signal length
N  = length(x);
// frequency spectrum
X = fft(x);
// amplitude spectrum
M = abs(X)/N;
// phase spectrum
Phi = [];
for i = 1:length(X)
    Phi(i) = atan(imag(X(i)), real(X(i)));
end
// normalized frequency
f = (0:(N/2))/N; 
k = size(f, '*');
// graphs
scf();
plot(x);
title('$x(k)$');
xlabel('$k$');
scf();
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(f, M(1:k), 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Amplitude');
xlabel('$\frac{f}{f_s}$');
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(f, Phi(1:k), 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Phase');
xlabel('$\frac{f}{f_s}$');


From the amplitude part of the spectrum it is obvious that there is a $300\,\mathrm{Hz}$ component in the signal. I would like to extract this frequency component from the original signal. So I have created a digital narrow band pass filter (based on the book). Namely there are formulas for such filter in the Chapter 19. I have chosen $f=0.03$ ($300\,\mathrm{Hz}$ at $10^4\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sampling frequency) and $bw=0.001$ (the passing frequencies will be $\left<295, 305\right>\,\mathrm{Hz}$). I have created the frequency response of the filter with the help of Scilab because I was curious how it looks like
// primary design inputs
bw = 0.001; // desired bandwidth as a fraction of sampling frequency
f  = 0.03;  // center of the bandpass as a fraction of sampling frequency (f = 300 Hz, fs = 10^4 Hz)

// auxiliary variables for design 
R = 1 - 3.0*bw;
K = (1 - 2*R*cos(2*%pi*f) + R^2)/(2 - 2*cos(2*%pi*f));

// difference equation coefficients
a0 = 1 - K;
a1 = 2*(K - R)*cos(2*%pi*f);
a2 = R^2 - K;
b1 = 2*R*cos(2*%pi*f);
b2 = -R^2; 

// coefficients of the polynomial in the numerator of the transfer function
B = [a0, a1, a2];
// coefficients of the polynomial in the denominator of the transfer function
A = [1.0, -b1, -b2];

// Frequency response

// polynomial in the numerator of the transfer function in z^-1
num = poly(B, 'invz', 'c');
// polynomial in the denominator of the transfer function in z^-1
den = poly(A, 'invz', 'c');

// relative frequency - w*k*Ts = 2*pi*f/fs*k, maximum frequency f = fs/2
// fr_max = f_max/fs = 0.5
fr = (0:0.0001:0.5);

// complex frequency response (transfer function is in z^(-1))
// z = exp(s*T) = exp([sigma + j*omega]*T)
hf = freq(num, den, exp(-%i*2*%pi*fr));

// amplitude
magnitude = abs(hf);

// phase
hf_imag = imag(hf);
hf_real = real(hf);
phase = atand(hf_imag, hf_real);

scf();
plot(fr, magnitude, 'Linewidth', 2);
title('Magnitude');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Mag(H(z))\,(\mathrm{-})$');
xgrid;
scf();
plot(fr, phase, 'Linewidth', 2);
title('Phase');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Arg(H(z))\,(\mathrm{^\circ})$');
xgrid;



Then I have tried to process the input signal via the above digital filter (again in Scilab)
y = filter(B, A, x);
scf();
subplot(2, 1, 1)
plot(t, x, 'b', 'Linewidth', 2);
xlabel('$t\,(\mathrm{s})$');
legend('$x(k)$');
xgrid;
subplot(2, 1, 2)
plot(t, y, 'r', 'Linewidth', 2);
xlabel('$t\,(\mathrm{s})$');
legend('$y(k)$');
xgrid;


I am not able to explain for myself why the filter output doesn't have constant amplitude. May I ask you for help?
Edit:
I have made an experiment when I have sent $x(k) = \sin(2\pi\cdot\frac{300}{10\,000}\cdot k)$ to the filter input and the signal at the filter output is $300\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine with fixed amplitude (after the transient decay).

Based on that it could be said that the original filtered signal contains $300\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine with variable amplitude.

You are assuming that your signal has a 300Hz component with constant amplitude. Are you sure about this? Take this step by step. To verify whether the filter is modulating the amplitude, or if the signal itself has a non-constant 300Hz component, you can synthesize a signal that has a strong constant 300Hz component, run it through your filter and see if the resulting signal has constant amplitude.


Based on that it could be said that the original filtered signal contains 300Hz  sine with variable amplitude.

Pretty much. The FFT can only give the total energy in that frequency bin of the entire signal. The energy at a specific frequency can definitely vary over time, but the FFT cannot resolve this since it has no time dimension. For that you would need a transform that's both a function frequency and of time. Examples would be the STFT (short term Fourier transform) or the wavelet transform.
